# C# report edit column values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report

I'm generating a report based on a database table. In the table I have genders saved as either 0 or 1 (male/female). In the report I would like to show the string value rather than showing the numbers. I tried messing with the code, ie.

```
this.ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.InventoryDataSet.Items);
foreach (DataRow row in this.InventoryDataSet.Items.Rows)
{
    if (row["gender"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        row["gender"] = "Male";
    }
}

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

However this breaks the report complelty (no data is shown). How can I achieve what I want?

**[edit]**

I came a little closer to the solution (I think) with this:

```
this.InventoryDataSet.Items.Columns.Add("genderVerbose", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in this.InventoryDataSet.Items.Rows)
{
    if (row["gender"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        row["genderVerbose"] = "Male";
    }
}
```

However now I get this error when trying to use the field in the report:

> Error 2   The Value expression for the text box ‘color’ refers to the
>   field ‘genderVerbose’.  Report item expressions can only refer to
>   fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate,
>   the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use
>   the correct case.

Comment: Did you tried like this:- `row[1]["gender"] = "Male";`

Comment: @R.T. `this.InventoryDataSet.Items.Rows[1]["gender"] = "Male";` Same result, no data is shown (no error either)

Comment: Did you tried to use the ItemArray option?

Comment: @R.T. ItemArray? What/how? :p

Comment: where do you get that error?

Comment: @Apostrofix The last one - when compiling/running

Comment: Have a look on this one: http://sqlandssrssolutions.blogspot.de/2013/10/the-value-expression-for-text-box-xyz.html And then you can try to debug and see if your `InventoryDataSet` actually contains the values/columns that you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning `Enum` values to the cells? `Enum.ToString()` by default gives the value name in code as the string. So with:

```
public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

You can just shove those into `DataGridView` cells and it will show that way. You can test values by

```
if ((Gender)row["gender"].Value == Gender.Male)
{
    // do things...
}
```

If you need this to be user-selectable, you can use the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.